# Upgrade issue 2.2.3 to 2.2.10 Class argument is invalid: xxx\xxx\Ui\Component\DataProvider\DataProvider

Tags: admin, magento2.2, grid, upgrade

I've got a store which has had a significant upgrade.

Gone from 2.2.3 to 2.2.10.  I've handled a lot of issues already.  The frontend seems fine.

Having a problem with backend. Getting errors when loading admin grids.  So just by logging in see errors like this:

`Class argument is invalid: Magento\AdminNotification\Ui\Component\DataProvider\DataProvider`

So I disable admin notifications via composer / CLI.

Then see similar error `Magento\ReleaseNotification`

So I disable release notifications via composer / CLI.

Can log in (or bypass dashboard) but then going to Catalog > Products for example

`Class argument is invalid: Magento\Catalog\UI\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider`

So just generally seems to be an issue with admin grids

I've Googled and read about changes in XML syntax but surely I can't have an issue with all the core modules?

Has anyone experienced the same issue? Or can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue specifically on dev install.  Deployment to staging and live went fine.

In summary I think I had a mixture of old and new files - although something outside of vendor folder.  So scaffolding for the framework.

I can't say exactly what went wrong.  I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises when the magento core files are corrupted or when the installation is not done properly.

You can try few things like :

- Reinstall the magento or
- Take the working code of /vendor directory and replace it to target directory.

Comment: It was outside of composer. But I agree a broken install.

Comment: Yes, I guess that might not be the solution using composer update, so updating the answer.